Express の res.cookie、res.redirect でリダイレクト先にクッキーが付与されない
以下のコード自体に問題はなくエラー等もありませんが、リダイレクトで/userpageに飛ぶとクッキーが無いためユーザー情報を取得できずエラーになります。
res.cookie('login', login, COOKIE_OPTION);
res.cookie('mail', mail, COOKIE_OPTION);
res.redirect('/userpage');

しかしリダイレクトせずに、ブックマークやURLを打ち込んでエンターを押すとクッキーは付いていた状態になっていてユーザーが表示されます。
そこで、302ではなく200でリダイレクトしようとしても、クッキーは付与されませんでした。
Expressの仕様上、変なキャッシュが有効になっているみたいな感じでクッキーが一時的に無い（戻るみたいな）感じでしょうか。
リダイレクト画面を/userpageにせず、文字で 「ログインは完了しました、こちらからユーザーページに入ります」 みたいに１クッション挟むことで凌いでいます。
ログアウト画面によくある5秒後にトップページに戻りますみたいなこともあまりしたくありません。
できればそのままリダイレクトでユーザー画面にクッキー付きで入りたいです。
検索したところによると、crosがどうとか、add-header credential trueなどと書いてありましたが、畑違いのようが気がします。
追加
「ログインは完了しました、こちらからユーザーページに入ります」
の画面をChromeのInspectで見ると、applicationタブのCookieは表示されませんが、Networkタブのresponse CookieにはCookieが表示されています。
その状態でこちらからユーザーページ等でアクセスするとクッキーが付与された状態になります。




リダイレクトで/userpageに飛ぶとクッキーが無いためユーザー情報を取得できずエラーになります。

応答ヘッダに Set-Cookie: ... がないからでは？
Fiddler などのツールを使って要求・応答をキャプチャしてどうなっているか調べてください。
以下に Fiddler で見た時の例を載せておきます。
Login ページでユーザーがログインに成功すると応答が返ってきて、赤枠で示したように応答ヘッダの Set-Cookie に認証クッキーが設定され、青枠で示したように Home/Privacy にリダイレクトされます。

ブラウザはリダイレクト指示に従って Home/Privacy を GET 要求しますが、その際、赤枠で示したように要求ヘッダに認証クッキー含まれてサーバーに送信されています。


応答ヘッダーにSetCookieは存在しました。ちなみにExpressではなくNativeのimport {createServer } from 'http';のres.writeHead(302, {Location: ~~, Set-Cookie: [~~~]})みたいにやると無事うまくできます。しかしこの場合app.get(~~~から全てをNativeに戻さなければなりません。Expressを使用した理由は、req.session.stateを保持するためです。

リダイレクト先のドメインが違うから Cookie が送信されないとか、Cookie が期限切れいうオチはないでしょうね？　上の 1 枚目の画像のようにサーバーからの応答に Set-Cookie: ... とリダイレクト指示をブラウザが受けていれば、あとはサーバー側は関係ないブラウザの仕事です。Set-Cookie: ... でブラウザが受けた Cookie が送信されないとするとリダイレクト先のドメインが違うとか Cookie 期限切れぐらいしか思い当たることはないのですが。

ちなみに、Cookie 期限切れというのは、上の 1 枚目の画像の赤枠の下の Set-Cookie: ... がその例です。

同一ドメインです。一応Strict Noneなどに設定しましたが、同じ状態になりました。期限はMax-Age=90000;です

また、iPhoneのChromeでログインを実行すると、ログインが完了しましたのページからトップページにとんでもクッキーがありませんでした。もう一度更新するとクッキーが反映されたようで、ユーザーアイコンが表示されログイン状態になりました。

ドメインも期限も問題ないとすると、あと自分が思いつくのは Cookie のパスぐらいです。Set-Cookie のパスの指定は path=/ になってますか？　（path=/ とすると、そのドメインのすべてのページ要求でクッキーがサーバーに送られます。Express でどうなるかは知りませんが、以前、クライアントスクリプトでクッキーを設定する際 path を指定しなかったら、クッキーがブラウザに保存される時そのページのディレクトリがパスに設定され、それを知らずにハマったことを思い出しました）

Path=/;になっております。Nginxで全てのキャッシュを削除する            if_modified_since off;
expires off;
etag off;
add_header Last-Modified $date_gmt;
add_header Cache-Control 'no-store, no-cache';
にすると、Inspectで見る限りクッキーが付与されていましたが、ブラウザページではログインされてない画面になりました。HTMLのキャッシュ関係かと思われます。

Nginxの設定で「ログインクッキーが存在すればNodeJS、なければ静的HTMLを表示にする」方法がよくなかったみたいです。全てExpressで受け入れれば、望み通りリダイレクトが綺麗に決まりました。

キャシュが関係あるとは思えません。上の回答の １ 枚目の画像にあるように Set-Cookie でブラウザが Cookie を受け取って、リダイレクト要求にしたがって 2 枚目の画像にあるように GET 要求を出した時に Cookie が要求ヘッダに含まれて送信されているか否かが問題です。そこはサーバー側は一切関係ないブラウザだけの話で、ドメイン、有効期限、パスに問題がなければ画像の通り Cookie は送信されるはずです。Fiddler を使ってそこを調べることはできませんか？

どうやらクッキーの取得方法がExpressとNginxで違うようでした。

最初の話は「リダイレクトで/userpageに飛ぶとクッキーが無いためユーザー情報を取得できずエラーになります」ということで、ブラウザから Set-Cookie で受け取った Cookie がサーバーに送信されないことが問題のように読めましたが、そうではなくて、ブラウザからサーバーには Cookie は送信されていたが、それを受けたサーバー側での扱いに問題があったという話ですか？

Cookie自体は送信されているようです。ログイン後のリダイレクト時にログインされたないHTMLファイルが表示されてしまっております。その後、ブラウザの更新ではなくトップバナーのリンクで/に更新すると、ログインされた状態になっています

Fiddler を導入することをお勧めします。Windows OS 以外は有償のツールですが・・・

やってみたいと思います。
